# Can I remove or add translations at run-time?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

We have a Spring-based web app which has internationalized text throughout. We use a series of appname_*.properties files with the key and translation pairs to store each language's translated text.

To get a translation, we go through `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext`, which is provided to an `ApplicationContextAware` class. We use it to call `applicationContext.getMessage(String key, String[] args, Locale locale)`, which returns the appropriate translation for a given key and arguments.

Is there a way to access the resources in order to add or remove one or more keys, with their associated translations, at run time? Meaning I don't want to change the .properties files before run-time, but rather I want to change the data built by reading those files during run-time.

Comment: May need to re-load the resource on every web request.